# Rails-API getting AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in API::V1::Controller#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

Hey I'm working on a simple API that takes info from the DB and returns it as a JSON object and its not quit working right. I keep getting:

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in API::V1::BusinessesController#index
>   Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

```
class API::V1::BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /businesses
  def index
    @businesses = Business.all

    render json: @businesses, status: :ok
    paginate json: @businesses, per_page: 50
  end

  # GET /business/#
  def show
    @business = Business.find(params[:id])

    render json: @business, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Also when I `$curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/businesses/1`  I only get `{"business":{"id":1}}` returned instead of the whole json object which should be `{"business":{id:1, name:costco, etc}}`

if more info is needed just let me know, the full repo is at github.com/dmonaco05/business-api Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is because you have `render` and `paginate` in your controller. Choose one.

```
def index
  @businesses = Business.all
  paginate json: @businesses, per_page: 50
end
```

The second problem is with your serializer. Add all required fields to your `UserSerializer` or delete the class to make it behave normally.

```
class BusinessSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, etc.
end
```

Comment: Perfect thanks so much!

I had just figured out the serializer portion when I saw this response.